# Find data in a column from a cell reference in another worksheet then copy some data to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have three worksheets in the workbook: First is the Info sheet where cell S1 has the Trainer Name to find in the second sheet named Classes.

Once the Trainer Name is found in the Classes sheet (Column H), I need to put that Trainer name in the Output sheet (next blank row, column A).

Then I also need to get Class Name from Classes (column A), Grad Date(Column P) and a few more data in columns X to AB.

The code runs but does not enter the data into the Output sheet. I've only tested two fields so far.

```
Sub GetClassData()
Dim cls As Worksheet
Dim shOUT As Worksheet
Set cls = Worksheets("Classes")
Set shOUT = Worksheets("Output")
Dim trName As Range
Set trName = Worksheets("Info").Range("S1")

cls.Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ' Decide if to copy based on column H
    thisvalue = Cells(x, 8).Value
    If thisvalue = trName.Value Then
        irow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With shOUT
            .Cells(irow, 1).Value = trName.Value
            .Cells(irow, 2).Value = trName.Offset(, -7).Value
        End With
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanations are inside the Code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetClassData()

Dim cls As Worksheet
Dim shOUT As Worksheet
Dim trName As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim thisvalue As String

Set cls = Worksheets("Classes")
Set shOUT = Worksheets("Output")
Set trName = Worksheets("Info").Range("S1")

With cls
    ' Find the last row of data in Column "A"
    FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through each row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        ' Decide if to copy based on column H
        thisvalue = .Range("H" & x).Value
        If thisvalue Like trName.Value Then ' <-- check the names
            iRow = shOUT.Cells(shOUT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

            shOUT.Range("A" & iRow).Value = thisvalue '<-- get Trainer Name
            shOUT.Range("B" & iRow).Value = .Range("A" & x).Value '<-- get Class Name for Classes
            ' add the rest of the thing you need to copy here

        End If
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Shai, thank you for the assist. i am getting an error though saying variable not found for the FinalRow code. > FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row... the .Cells part is being highlighted

Comment: @CieloSalas try again, strange, I didn't copy the `Dim` line (should work now)

Comment: i am now getting an error on > thisvalue = .Range("H" & x).Value. i tried setting the Dim to Variant but when i run the code, nothing happens in shOUT

Comment: @CieloSalas  same as before, added that Dim, see if t works now

Comment: no longer getting an error but the shOUT sheet is still blank