# vba Find cell data through columns and if nothing then look at the next column

Tags: vba, excel

This is in connection to [Find data in a column from a cell reference in another worksheet then copy some data to another worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548301/find-data-in-a-column-from-a-cell-reference-in-another-worksheet-then-copy-some)
I need to find a class name if they graduate by a certain month. The month to be used for the find reference is in another sheet. graduation months should be searched in column G first, and if search finds nothing then to search in the next column.
This is what i have so far, but this searches one column only. i am not sure how to go about searching the other columns yet. search should stop the first instance that the value is found.

```
Sub Hierarchy()

Dim shOUT As Worksheet
Dim nfo As Worksheet
Dim Month As Range

Dim a As Long
Dim thisvalue As String

Set nfo = Worksheets("Info")
Set shOUT = Worksheets("Output")
Set Month = nfo.Range("A2")

With shOUT
        ' Loop through each row
        For a = 2 To 10
            thisvalue = .Cells(a, 7).Value
            If thisvalue Like Month.Value Then ' <-- check the names

            nfo.Range("A5").Value = .Cells(a, 2).Value
            nfo.Range("A6").Value = .Cells(1, 7).Value

            End If
        Next a
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just Add a `GoTo` to your if-statement. Google "GoTo in VBA" if you don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon an extra loop, plus some minor edits might suffice:

```
For b = 7 To 8
    For a = 2 To 10
        thisvalue = .Cells(a, b).Value
        If thisvalue Like Month.Value Then ' <-- check the names
            nfo.Range("A5").Value = .Cells(a, 2).Value
            nfo.Range("A6").Value = .Cells(1, b).Value
            Finished = True
            Exit For '<-- skip the rest, we're done
        End If
    Next a
    If Finished = True Then Exit For
Next b
```

It might need some tweaks (as I'm not too sure about the updates to A5 and A6), but the concept is sound.

I've added a couple of variables (b, and Finished) that you'll need to declare.

Comment: i have declared b as Long and Finished as Boolean but i am getting an error on Next a now. Compile Error Next without for

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the help. wanted to let you know that i added an End If to close the If Finished statement.

Comment: Ah, yes. I guess you must have split the `If-Then` over multiple lines. When it's all on one line, no `End If` is required.